# how to get CSV from items of a html list control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web

`enter code here`I have an html UL control that gets dynamicaly populated with LI (list items).
I want a javascript function to process the items of the list and need a csv of all the list items.

I am trying this and getting errors:

**javascript:**

```
var ulTags = document.getElementById("basic_tag_handler");
var listItem = ulTags.getElementsByTagName("li");

var stringOfTags = '';
for (var i = 0; i < listItem.length-1; i++) {
stringOfTags += listItem[i].innerHTML & "," );
}

alert (stringOfTags);
```

**html:**

```
<ul id="basic_tag_handler" runat ="server" ></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a syntax error when you have `&`, I suppose, you meant `+`. Also, you need to remove the trailing comma, but however better way would be to use `Array.map` and `Array.join`

```
var stringOfTags = [].map.call(listItem, function(elm){
   return elm.innerHTML;
}).join(",");
```

Comment: when i use alert(stringOfTag); to see the value i get an erorr that stringOfTag is undefined ???  also, i have onepoblem the last LI contains a textbox that breaks the innerhtml values retrevial of the items i want. can type be validated first or loop all -1 LI items